# adding for loop or any thing to call list in the function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, for-loop

I am trying to use either for loop or anything else to put list inside parameters **reporter ='arg'**

for instance list **['arg','AFG','ALB','DZA']**
and then save them in one dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import world_trade_data as wits    
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 6)


Countery_IMPORT = wits.get_indicator('MPRT-TRD-VL', reporter='arg', year='all',partner='wld',datasource='tradestats-trade',name_or_id='name')
```

Comment: I used this countery = ['AFG','ALB','DZA']
for x in countery: but not working

Answer (score 1):

Simple list comprehension to [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)

```
import pandas as pd
import world_trade_data as wits

pd.set_option("display.max_rows", 6)

Countery_IMPORT = pd.concat(
    [
        wits.get_indicator(
            "MPRT-TRD-VL",
            reporter=arg,
            year="all",
            partner="wld",
            datasource="tradestats-trade",
            name_or_id="name",
        )
        for arg in ["arg", "AFG", "ALB", "DZA"]
    ]
)

Countery_IMPORT
```